# Laravel blade template view HTML::style not linking in sub folder

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-4

I have:

```
{{HTML::style('css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css')}}
```

Which in the source code comes out as:

```
http://www.view.local/laravel/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

Which is wrong.

It should be:

```
http://www.view.local/laravel/public/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

But of course I don't want it to show the laravel part of the source.

The project directory is:

```
http://www.view.local/laravel
```

Which is working fine for everything else.

How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: Your public folder should be the root directory of your website, it should not be in the url. You should configure your webserver so that `public/` is you websites root.

Answer (score 0):

This works exactly as expected.

Public folder should be configured as root directory for laravel applications. You should set `path_to/laravel/public` as directory for your virtual host. That will solve the issue.

Making `path_to/laravel` as root directory will make your application vulnerable. Always make sure that you give web access only to public directory. If you are hosting on a linux based web server, the content of public folder should go to public_html folder.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel links all the resources file to the public folder so you can use the asset() function in this way:

```
<link href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

where `style.css` must be in `public/` folder